# Joomla error: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: joomla

I just transferred my website from local to production subserver and can't access it anymore.

Here are the errors I got:

> Warning: require_once(/home/gtblogme/public_html/plugins/content/loadformmaker/loadformmaker.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/gtblogme/public_html/libraries/src/Plugin/PluginHelper.php on line 253
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/gtblogme/public_html/plugins/content/loadformmaker/loadformmaker.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/gtblogme/public_html/libraries/src/Plugin/PluginHelper.php on line 253

How can I eliminate these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Go into phpmyadmin, and go to the #__extensions table.  Search for that plugin and unpublish.

My guess is that production server is on different version of PHP or some other different and that particular extension is incompatible.